# Difference between 場所 and 所

Tags: word-choice

> ２６日は、１９日と別の**場所**で２回目の噴火がありました。
>   On the 26th there was a second eruption in a place different from the 19th.
>   しかし、２６日に噴火が起こった**所**は、頂上から西側に５００ｍぐらいの**所**でした。
>   However, the place where the eruption occurred on the 26th was around 500m to the west of the summit.

For along time now I've been happily reading both 場所 and 所 as 'place' without thinking about the difference. Are they interchangeable or is there a deeper reason for using different words in the above text?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference between 場所 and 所 can be quite subtle when talking about an actual place. 場所 is a bit more formal than 所, but many people do not distinguish them very much and will use both to vary the language a bit.

> 遺跡が発見された場所 = place where the ruins were found
>
> 会議の時間と場所を決める = set the time and place for the meeting
>
> 国が所有している場所 = government-owned land
>
> 駅から５分くらいの所に住んでいる = live five minutes from the station
>
> 彼氏の背中のかゆい所をかく = scratch the boyfriend's itchy spot in the back

One difference between 場所 and 所 is that 場所 always refers to a place in the literal sense, but 所/ところ can also be used for more abstract things. In modern Japanese, it is usual to write it in hiragana when using it in the abstract sense.

> 今やっているところです = (I am) doing it now
>
> 今日のところは許してやる = I will forgive you for today
>
> 勉強が終わったところです = I just finished my homework
>
> それは政府の関知するところではない = that is none of the government's business

Answer (score 2):

There is a subtle difference between 所 and 場所.
２６日は、１９日と別の場所で２回目の噴火がありました。 sounds more formal than ２６日は、１９日と別の所で２回目の噴火がありました。 . But it's very very subtle difference.When I emphasize ""place"", I may use "場所". For example, when news reporters report where murder occur,they may say like 殺人事件が起きた”場所”はこちらの～(But 所 is also used... So very subtle...). By the way, second phrase contans 所 two times in one sentence, and it seems little strange(It looks like 頭痛で頭が痛い）.